# How to associate a custom file extension with the MSBuild Tools in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Take any C# project file (`*.csproj` and rename it to `*.build` and then open it with VS Code. It will be recognized as XML.

What I would like is to associate VsCode [MSBuild Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qub.qub-msbuild) with that custom extension. I already tried provide a file association like

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.build":"csproj"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`files.associations` changes the language type, so the example you gave tells vscode that `*.build` has the language id `csproj`. There is no language id `csproj` by default and this extension does not add one. What you really wanted was this:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.build":"xml"
}
```

That tells vscode to treate `.build` files as `xml` files.

However, that still won't fix your problem. I looked at the code in the extension by installing it and digging around (unfortunately it isn't on github) and I can see that it explicitly checks for files that match one of the following:

```
RegExp("\\.props$"),
RegExp("\\.targets$"),
RegExp("\\..*proj$")
```

`.build` does not match that and therefore the extension will not work on those files.

I suggest leaving a review on the marketplace asking for two things:
1) the extension source to be put on github
2) the author to make the extensions parsed configurable in user settings

You may also consider alternative extensions such as [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintoy.msbuild-project-tools).

Comment: Thanks for the answer however as a side note although your other extension suggestion looks better it does not support latest version of Code. I posted at https://github.com/tintoy/msbuild-project-tools-vscode/issues/10

Comment: you're welcome for the answer. If there is a reason for not accepting the answer please let me know so I can answer any remaining questions.

Comment: Also, the latest version of VS Code is 1.15, not 1.13. the extension only supports versions >= 1.14. unless there is a reason that you cannot upgrade past 1.13, you should consider upgrading to the latest version

Comment: Yeah thnks I figure it also that my version was a bit outdated. Sorry for not accepted the answer just missed it. However I do not see however can I support my custom extension even with the alternative tool you suggested. Can you please clarify?

Comment: ok it looks like your alternative tool registers a new MSBuild language that I can associate my custom extension as long as this bug is fixed. https://github.com/tintoy/msbuild-project-tools-vscode/issues/11#issuecomment-327920341